# How to increment counter value for each dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

I am trying to increment the **react state counter** based on some option selection from the dropdown menu. The problem is I want to **preserve** the counter value and continuously increment based on condition like option `"Test"` is selected.

I am using below code to increment a counter if `"Test"` is selected in both the dropdown

```
{this.state.DownloadPrepare == "Test" ? this.state.Identify == "Test" : this.state.CalcNoOfObs+1}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-shirley-flznm

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0,
    listOne: null,
    listTwo: null
  };

  incrementIfTest = event => {
    console.log(event.target.name);

    if (
      //check if is already selected, do not want to double count
      event.target.value === "Test" &&
      this.state[event.target.name] !== "Test"
    ) {
      //increment count
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        counter: this.state.counter + 1,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      });
      //decrease count if they remove Test selection, cannot be below 0.
    } else if(this.state[event.target.name] === "Test"){
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        counter: this.state.counter > 0 ? this.state.counter - 1 : 0,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{this.state.counter}</h4>
        <select name="listOne" onChange={this.incrementIfTest}>
          <option />
          <option>DownloadPrepare</option>
          <option>Test</option>
        </select>
        <select name="listTwo" onChange={this.incrementIfTest}>
          <option />
          <option>DownloadPrepare</option>
          <option>Test</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Make use of the `onChange()` event-listener on the Dropdown (select tag). We can pass in the event and have access to the selected option through `event.target.value`. If it equals `Test`, we just increment the `count`

Comment: Awesome! You're very welcome @Snehal. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a script for on click you can do on the change as well I hope It's useful for you.

Thanks

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      DownloadPrepare: "Test",
      Identify: "",
      CalcNoOfObs: 0
    };
  }

click() { // make your function what you want on change 
    this.state.DownloadPrepare == "Test"
      ? this.setState({
          Identify: "Test"
        })
      : this.setState({
          CalcNoOfObs: this.state.CalcNoOfObs + 1
        });
  }



<button onClick={() => this.click()}>click</button>
```